# MVC login users automatically

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, razor, forms-authentication

I have a C# MVC application that uses Simple Membership to authenticate users. For user convenience, I would like to login visitors automatically if they have authenticated themselves to the site in the past using the browser. The goal is to save known users the step of entering in user credentials. What would be a recommended way of going about it?

Comment: How do you know that the person sitting at the computer is the person that was sitting at the computer the last time?  Think about cyber cafe's, libraries, schools, etc...

Comment: @ErikFunkenbusch: "remember me" that issues persistent cookie is a common solution, Google, Facebook, Twitter and hundreds of other websites use it. Even despite all the risk it involves.

Comment: @WiktorZychla - "remember me" is an option, not an automatic, always authenticate the browser with the first person that ever used it for all eternity feature

Comment: @ErikFunkenbusch: Thanks, these are both very useful comments. How do you authenticate the browser?